# Rotation animation of empty object and the keyframes seem to be the problem

Tags: animation, keyframes, empty

I'm trying to animate an empty object that should rotate to create an animation only with the keyframe and the empty need to do a full rotation for the animation but every time I try to put 360 degree on the last keyframe and press ( <kbd>I</kbd>) to set the keyframes not only it stays orange but the rotation is completely messed up

Putting the first keyframe
[image]

Putting The Second keyframe
[image]

Pressing (I) to insert the keyframe (but the rotation is still orange)
[image]

The Rotation is ruined and put at 0.00001 degree for some reason
[image]

[image]

Comment: This exact workflow works fine for me. Can you share your .blend file and edit your question with the link please: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi @Knetto. I simply deleted the keyframe, typed in 360 and inserted a keyframe at frame 161 and it works for me. What version of Blender are you using? I'm on 3.3.0. My .blend here https://file.io/OgA9Kd6fDxwi (P.S. blend-exchange doesn't seem to be working, so hopefully this link works for you)